# Terraform - Output a map with key as value of for_each while resource creation

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I am trying to solve below :

At first, Create resources based on the entries of the list provided to the resource. Below is the tf code, i have written for it :

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "application_key_vault" {
  foreach             = toset(var.app_names)
  name                = "${each.value}-kv"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  tenant_id           = local.tenant_id
  sku_name            = "standard"

  dynamic "contact" {
    for_each = var.key_vault_contact_emails
    content {
      email = contact.value
    }
  }

  network_acls {
    default_action = "Deny"
    bypass         = "AzureServices"
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = local.key_vault_allowed_subnets_set
  }

  tags = local.all_tags
  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.aks_resource_group]
}
```

Now, lets say "app_names" has values ["app1", "app2", "app3"]. And the keyvaults created have ids ["id1", "id2", "id3"].
Is there a way i can create a map of above dynamically , which looks like this :

```
{
 "app1" : "id1",
 "app2" : "id2",
 "app3" : "id3",
}
```

I tried using "output" something like this, but not able to figure out how should I get app_name which is used in creation of each keyvault :

```
output "application_app_name_by_key_vault_id_map" {
  value = { for akv in azurerm_key_vault.application_key_vault : <not sure how to get app_name here> => akv.id }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are creating the `azurerm_key_vault` resource with `for_each`, it acts like any other key value map. In other words, you can do the following:

```
output "application_app_name_by_key_vault_id_map" {
  value = { for k, v in azurerm_key_vault.application_key_vault: k => v.id }
}
```